# What does this code mean: return '/' === substr( get_option( 'permalink_structure' ), -1, 1 );

Tags: php, wordpress, string

What does this code mean, I read a wordpress plugin and saw this.

`return '/' === substr( get_option( 'permalink_structure' ), -1, 1 );`

I know what `get_option( permalink_structure )` mean.

When I print this code , the number 1 is printed , my permalink_structure is "/%postname%/"

Comment: It returns `true` when the last character of `get_option( 'permalink_structure' )` is `/`, otherwise it returns `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return '/' === substr( get_option( 'permalink_structure' ), -1, 1 )`

let's break this code.

1. `get_option( 'permalink_structure' )`
   here `get_option` is a function that takes a string as input and as a result, it gives us a value from the `wp_options` table by matching the option name which we passed as an argument.
2. `substr( get_option( 'permalink_structure' ), -1, 1 )`
   `substr` is an extraction function for a string you can read about in detail on the [documentation page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php). **string**, **offset**, **length** are 3 params for this function. In the example option value is a string, `-1` is offset and `1` is the length. so here we're telling the function, here is the string now goto to offset `-1`, which is the first char from the end, and then from that point extract the `1` character.
3. `'/' === substr( get_option( 'permalink_structure' ), -1, 1 )` 
   here `===` is called strict comparison, which means data type and value both should be same. so from point no. 2 code, we're expecting `/` as `substr` output and then we're comparing it with `===`
4. `return '/' === substr( get_option( 'permalink_structure' ), -1, 1 )`
   here using `return` we're returning the result of the comparison which will be either true or false.

> I print this code, the number 1 is printed, and my permalink_structure is "/%postname%/"

1 is being printed because you're getting true as the result and if you'll echo/print the boolean `true` it will get print as `1`